# Audio Streaming between iPhone to Google-glass headset via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, google-glass

I am trying to listen to my iPhone songs into Google-glass headset via Bluetooth. First tried all iTunes songs access to `UITableView`, but now my Problem is how to route iPhone audio to the Google-glass Bluetooth headset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/LGBluetooth for bluetooth stuff (connecting to google glass, and streaming your music data), the other stuff "how google glass receives the audio data" you need to find in their documentation.